# my php function stops after 30 seconds after running

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, hosting, cpanel

I have made a function in my Laravel application to send a message to my subscribers when I publish an entry, the problem is that it stops when it goes by the subscriber 28 and does not follow.

I've been researching and it seems that php by default for the script when it takes 30 seconds, I changed the configuration and even the support of my hosting has done for me. But still it is still cutting when it takes about 30 seconds.

Attached image of the php configuration of the cpanel

[image]

Comment: Web scripts should not run that long. if you need a script to be run longer than 30 seconds, I suggest you run it from the console.

Comment: You should probably offload this to a queue and let it work on the background. What if you have 10,000 subscribers one day? The script would take hours to complete. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#introduction

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time 30 seconds is default maximum execution time in various PHP configurations

Comment: @Loek 
Thanks for your answer, this could do it in a hosting without needing to execute anything in terminal? I've been seeing examples that use commands and I'm not sure. Thank you

Comment: @jlgf Depends on the hosting provider, but most providers give an option to run CRON jobs. Laravel has a neat way of running background workers in a CRON job, you could probably look into that: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling . Rule of thumb: if your script takes more than 5 seconds to run, it should probably run in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Php has a max execution time, you can set a new time limit:

**php script**

- ini_set('max_execution_time', 100); //100 seconds
- ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); // for infinite

**htaccess**

- php_value max_execution_time 300

Caution, scripts in an infinity loop will run forever.

Answer (score 0):

Put that on top of your php script.
Just change amount of seconds.

```
max_execution_time = 10
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem. This will only break the code sooner and even fewer gets the message

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cpanel/WHM , go to "MultiPHP INI Editor"(Basic Mode) and select PHP version .

Then edit max_execution_time.

Screenshot attached :

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Za4XK.png)